# scroll FlatList in a ScrollView in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a `FlatList` inside a `View`, and the `View` is at the end of a `ScrollView`, I want to scroll the `FlatList` while the whole scroll at the end of the page. But I can't do that. So what should I do to let my `FlatList` have the ability to scroll while inside a `ScrollView`? The body is like this:

```
<ScrollView>
  <View/>
  <View/>
  <View>
    <View/>
    <FlatList/>
  </View>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this issue by adding some code in to `View` which wraps the `ScrollView` and the another `View` which wraps the `FlatList`

So first of all define a user define variable in `state` inside the constructor.

```
this.state={
    .....
    enableScrollViewScroll : false
    ....
 }
```

Then add following code as a `props` to the `View` which wrap the `ScrollView`

```
onStartShouldSetResponderCapture={() => {
  this.setState({ enableScrollViewScroll: true });
}}
```

Add `scrollEnabled={this.state.enableScrollViewScroll}` prop to `ScrollView`

And Finally add following to the View which wraps the FlatList( immediate parent )

```
onStartShouldSetResponderCapture={() => {
   this.setState({ enableScrollViewScroll: false });

  if (this.refs.myList.scrollProperties.offset === 0 && 
     this.state.enableScrollViewScroll === false) {
     this.setState({ enableScrollViewScroll: true });
 }
}}
```

Here `myList` is the referance of `FlatList`